# C:\Program was unexpected at this time. Trying to compile C++ library to .dll via .bat file from Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: c++

This question is not connected with specific library but I will try to explain full process what is the issue:

1. I am trying to compile minkowski.cc code of boost library via bat file like this: [image: Screenshot1]
2. Compiling works fine and I can compile and run 32 bit version.
3. The problem happens when I want to compile 64 bit version. Again it is not the issue of library but compiling issue. To compile I open "Visual Studio Community 2017 Command Prompt" (I have C++ development installed), by default compiler is set to x86 - 32 bit version: [image: Screenshot2]
4. To change compiler from 32bit to 64 bit I type: **vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64**
5. However I get error: **C:\Program was unexpected at this time.**
   [image: Screenshot3]

I am searching how to change compiler from 32 bit to 64 bit for a week in stack-overflow and google queries but cannot find a correct answer. Please help.

Comment: If it only parses C:\Program it means most likely that you need to provide the full path inside quotes `" "` So it doesn't take spaces as separators between parameters

Comment: Use the x64 command line directly.

Comment: You already started the developer command prompt.  Starting it again is not a good idea.  Do favor the IDE to get past basic speed-bumps like this.

Comment: What do you by the full path? Could you give an example? If Command Prompt points to correct directory and I just need to change the compiler. If I type something like this it produces a syntaxt error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL There are 2 types of paths: relative path, or full path. Regardless of which one you use, if such path contains spaces - it must be inside quotes.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it does not contain spaces as it is calling a file and then a function inside it. Hans Passant suggestion worked, but I still do not get why I cannot change compiler inside command prompt.

Comment: The comments you got are not helpful, it is a command inside vcvarsall.bat that caused this problem.  You must not run it twice.  If you need to target a different architecture then pick the right shortcut in the Start menu.  You want Visual Studio 2017 > x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2017.

Comment: @HansPassant solved the issue thank you.